# Are there multiple ways to create UITableViewCells programmatically or just one?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

A little background.  I've been doing tutorials using Swift to do small simple projects.  I have a hypothesis that if I can gain a better understanding of properly reading Apple's documentation and implementing projects based on following a list of steps (do a., then b., and then c., etc.) then I will be able to tackle any task no matter which framework and can follow Apple's documentation line for line.  Am I correct in my hypothesis, believing this is how a programmer usually thinks on the job to achieve projects if they are unfamiliar with a framework or is the documentation not meant be read like a book from A-Z?

I was hoping to notice a pattern after following multiple UITableView tutorials in hopes all UITableView's are built in the same way and I can tuck this knowledge away mentally for later re-use or just save the project for reference.  In the example below, the programmer is calling UITableView's dequeResuableCell function inside it's datasource's cellForRowAtIndex function:

```
//datasource required function
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCell

        cell.configCell(with: ToDoItem(title: ""))

        return cell
    }
```

After reading Apple's documentation for the 100th time, I wouldn't have thought UITableViewCells were accomplished in this manner, using this function, and by putting objects together in this type of way.  Are processes like this explained precisely word for word in Apple's documentation or is this considered an art form on behalf of the programmer.  Could configuring the UITableViewCell have been accomplished inside the tableview class versus the class that is the datasource?

Comment: That is the customary way of creating the cell.  If you create a UITableViewController subclass in Xcode, the standard template contains the above code.

Comment: @vacawama I never took the time to realize, thank you. My eyes would always glance over commented out code as many times I've created this template.  What if you wanted to work with a framework such as Bluetooth or a framework you've never worked with which doesn't have a UI template?  Can you explain your process?

Comment: Yes, you should read Apple's documentation to see what properties and methods are available.  If the initializer for an object you need takes another object, then you need to read the documentation for how to create that object. There's nothing like looking at other's examples.  Apple provides code examples.  Stack Overflow is also good place for this, of course.  Auto complete is handy as well.  You can try typing the names of settings that you think an object might have and see what Auto complete suggests.  Option-clicking on a variable provides links to the docs.